# What is Datastructure of LazyTreeGridStoreModel?

Tags: dojo

I am working with LazyTreeGridStoreModel .

And need to form a json datastructure with child parent relationship that can support LazyTreeGridStoreModel.

I saw the sample given in the dojo site but couldn't find the relationship between parent child.The below sample provided on dojo site.

```
data = {
  identifier: 'id',
  label: 'name',
  items: [
    {id: 'AF', name:'Africa', children: true},
    {id: 'EG', name:'Egypt' , children: false},
    {id: 'KE', name:'Kenya',
      children:[
        {id: 'Nairobi', name:'Nairobi', type:'city'},
        {id: 'Mombasa', name:'Mombasa', type:'city'}
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Where i can declare the children of

```
{id: 'AF', name:'Africa', children: true},
```

Answer (score 1):

Abhisek

You will need to implement the mechanism in your JSON data and in your datastore.
Typically, an attribute is added to the JSON data to indicate the parent-id.
For example:

```
{id: 'EG', name:'Egypt' , children: false, '$ref': 'AF'}
```

Here '$ref' is referring to the parent's id for this child.

The LazyTreeGridStoreModel will call store.fetch() with a query object {parentId: value} and you can extend your store (QRS for example) and implement isItemLoaded(), loadItem(), and getValues() to return the children items appropriate for your data

The following URL has a nice example on how to implement this with queryreadstore:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-dojotreegrid/index.html

Also see:
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/grid/tests/test_treegrid_model_lazy.html

View the source to see how the children in the JSON data are using a "$ref" attribute to indicate their parent